# A way to find the localized version of the string "Calendar"

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS api to query people's calendar items.  Often, a calendar name is simply "Calendar", which isn't useful, so in those cases, I would like to replace the name with the email address of the room.

However, in France, "Calendar" is "Calendrier".

Is there a way in EWS to get the localized string that represents "Calendar"?

Comment: What if the user has more than one calendar folder?

Comment: @john: then those users will be in the same boat they are now, and everyone else will be better off for a net gain.

Comment: Or,you could find a way to determine which folders contain Calendar items.

Comment: I know how to find them.  I just want to provide the user with a more specific name, "Calendar" isn't cutting it.  I think I must've worded my question wrong.  I'm not trying to find calendar folders using a string, I'm trying to replace the name "Calendar" with at least an email address or something.

Comment: Interesting. I'll assume you have a legitimate reason to rename folders on behalf of users. I'm using Outlook 2013, and in the "Calendar" view, each calendar is followed by the name of the account it comes from.

Comment: I never said I wanted to rename the calendar.  I want to present a better name to our users in our application.  A drop down box with 10 items that all say "Calendar" isn't useful.  Can we be past the part where you think I'm doing something idiotic now?

Comment: I suggest you update your question to make it clear you're not "doing something idiotic". I then recommend you do something like what Outlook 2013 does, and append the account name to the name of _every_ calendar folder. That way you don't have to worry about how they are named.

Comment: Make that an answer and I will mark it accepted.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you do something like what Outlook 2013 does, and append the account name to the name of every calendar folder. That way you don't have to worry about how they are named.

Note that Outlook appends either the name of the account, or the name of the data file, if it finds the folder in a data file. I have one that says "Calendar *Archive*", for instance.